# При добавлении :nth-child(2) margin-bottom изменяется для всех .topbar ul,а хотелось,чтоб только для него

Tags: css, html5, веб-программирование, вёрстка, табличная-верстка

```css
.genre {
    height: 450px;
    width: 18%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    margin-left: 12%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.genre h3 {
    padding-top: 4%;
    padding-left: 14%;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
.menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
}
.topbar{
    list-style: none;
}
.topbar ul{
    display:none;
    margin-left:20%;
    margin-top: -5%;
}

.topbar ul:nth-child(2){
    display:none;
    margin-left:20%;
    margin-top: -10%;
}

.topbar:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
.genre a {
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(129, 126, 126);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 70px;
}

.genre a:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
        <div class="genre">
            <ul class="menu">
                <h3>Выберите жанр:</h3>
                <li class="topbar"><a href="#">Боевики</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Бефстроганов</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Гусь с яблоками</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Крупеник новгородский</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="brd">Раки по-русски</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="topbar"><a href="#">Детективы</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Вареники</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Жаркое по-харьковски</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Капустняк черниговский</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="brd">Потапцы с помидорами</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="topbar"><a href="#">Комедия</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Суп-харчо</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Лилибдж</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Чихиртма</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Шашлык</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="topbar"><a href="asia.html" class="brd">Драмы</a></li>
                <li class="topbar"><a href="asia.html" class="brd">Трагедии</a></li>
                <li class="topbar"><a href="asia.html" class="brd">Исторические фильмы</a></li>
                <li class="topbar"><a href="asia.html" class="brd">Триллеры</a></li>
                <li class="topbar"><a href="asia.html" class="brd">Фантастика</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: если вы хотите изменить `ul` во втором  `topbar`, то пишите: `topbar:nth-child(2) ul`

Comment: все равно изменяет первый ul на margin-top

Comment: нашел проблему, но почему то он у меня считает 2 элемент за третий.То есть,должно быть nth-child(2) срабатывать,но он считает его за первый элемент, а nth-child(3) уже за второй

Comment: потому что у вас `h3` в одном контейнере с `topbar`

Comment: h3 - первый чайлд, первый топбар - второй чайлд, второй топбар - третий чайлд. попробуйте `.nth-of-type`